# Access Denied to a Module's memory

Tags: memory, assembly, readprocessmemory

As a hobby, I've been putting time into learning about binaries. I'm creating a program that does mostly what Ollydbg does. I figure taking on such a big project will teach me the all I want to know about PEs. Right now I'm working on a dialog that resembles Ollydbg's memory map and lists out the heaps and sections associated with each module but am running into some problems with access rights to system modules. I start off by opening a file and running it as a debuggee. I then

```
invoke OpenProcess,PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,AttachedPID

invoke ReadProcessMemory,eax,MemMapBaseAddress,offset MemMapMappingBuffer,1024h,offset MemMapNumberOfBytesWritten
invoke GetLastError
```

This works for about 30% of the modules that I tried to read from. The rest give me a 12B error, Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed. One module that gives me this error is ntdll. So I did some researching and found that I probably don't have permissions to the section in memory I was trying to access. So I tried changing the protection of that bit of memory with

```
invoke OpenProcess,PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,AttachedPID
push eax

invoke VirtualProtectEx,eax,offset MemMapBaseAddress,1024h,PAGE_READWRITE,offset OldProtect
invoke GetLastError

pop eax
invoke ReadProcessMemory,eax,MemMapBaseAddress,offset MemMapMappingBuffer,1024h,offset MemMapNumberOfBytesWritten
invoke GetLastError
```

and I get an error 5, access denied, for VirtualProtectEx. I've tried running the program as the administrator as well and got the same results. Any idea about whats keeping me from reading the PE header of a module loaded as a debuggee?

Comment: What privileges/rights are you running under?  It sounds as though you do not have System level rights which will prevent you from accessing the memory of NTDLL.dll

Comment: @DavidHoelzer that's the problem. I don't have system privileges. Lots of research ahead of me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must run your executable as administrator and you may also need to adjust your token privelage to [SeDebugPrivelage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--) if you want full access to an external process's memory.